# Administering Server 2012 with RSAT on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2012, windows

The small charity I work for has just purchased Windows Server 2012. We are a small organization with 20 desktop users and 5 laptop users. All the PCs and laptops are Windows 7 Enterprise.

From what I have read on numerous forums, you have to run RSAT from a Windows 8 PC in order to administer Windows Server 2012. I came across a couple of posts that said that you can use Windows 7 RSAT but "it is not recommended."

What I want to know is:

1. Why is it not recommended?
2. What potential pitfalls exist if the older RSAT is used?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with using the legacy RSAT tools is that they won't be aware of new functionality in 2012 and could cause headaches down the road.

Your best bests are:

- administer through an RDP session to the 2012 server
- setup a Win8 PC for your IT administrator

You could setup a VM but at that point you might as well RDP to the server.

But come on...that small of a shop, how often are you messing with the server or any of the RSAT tools?

Comment: Thanks TC - your'e right about frequency of use of RSAT, it would basically be for for setting up shared folders\printers, and creating new users\groups...and pssibly tweaking Group Policy  Just thought I'd ask though.

Comment: Well, since they just bought it, he'll probably be messing with it pretty often, at first.

Comment: absolutely...at least until I get my head properly round it all :)  BTW, would I still have to create a Central Store of the admx files a la Server 2003?

Answer (score -3):

You can use [5nine-manager-for-hyper-v-free](http://www.5nine.com/5nine-manager-for-hyper-v-free.aspx). The free version can manage up to two Hyper-V hosts.

Comment: Why do you put -1? I have found no other way to connect to the Server 2012 Hyper-V from Windows 7. Only the RDP and 5nine. Mention of 5nine I found on [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/30840b0f-07bf-439b-85f5-82710c0030ca)

Comment: I think the downvotes are because the OP isn't asking about Hyper-V management.

Comment: the downvotes are because of meta serverfault.

Comment: I answered the question written in subject.